# Creating new column based on cells from multiple column data frame that are like a string

Tags: r

I know that all of the rows have a value that is like the string I'm interested in.  However, I don't know which column it will be in.  I want to create a new column with the values.

For example, take the data frame below, where I want the string "ap"

```
       V1  V2
1   apple  orange
2   banana apricot
3   grape  apple
```

Based on this I want to create a third variable V3:

```
     V3
1    apple
2    apricot
3    apple
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you possible share the data using `dput()`? If you are not familiar with `dput()` I recommenced to take a look at how to produce a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `grape` and `apple` both habe `ap`. Do you want to look at just the beginning? Then it could be something like `df$V3 <- apply(df, 1, grep, pattern="^ap", value=TRUE)`.

Comment: Also `grep("^ap", unclass(t(dat)), value=TRUE)` would work if you are sure that only one match exists per row.

Comment: @lukeA Thank you so much, this is perfect.  Yes, I only needed to looked the beginning.

Comment: @EricFail I can't share the actual data, though I would if I could.  Thank you for the reproducible example link.

Comment: I understand, most often it's not possible to share production data. If you take a look at the link you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your variables are an arrays of strings.

```
var V1 = ["apple", "banana", "grape"];
var V2 = ["orange", "apricot", "apple"];

var V3 = [];

V1.forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.indexOf("ap") === 0) {
        V3.push(element);
    }
});

V2.forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.indexOf("ap") === 0) {
        V3.push(element);
    }
});
```